# Error while connecting spring to MongoDb (Docker)

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I'm dockerizing my applications, I got a problem with the spring side while trying to connect to the database, (on local everything was working), even when I running my docker-compose the database is working, even if i run my local with the docker-compose running is working.
The error I got on docker is this:

```
    org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}]; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:95) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.0.jar!/:3.4.0]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:3044) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.0.jar!/:3.4.0]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:2980) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.0.jar!/:3.4.0]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:2667) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.0.jar!/:3.4.0]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:2649) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.0.jar!/:3.4.0]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:902) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.0.jar!/:3.4.0]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.findAll(SimpleMongoRepository.java:444) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.0.jar!/:3.4.0]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.findAll(SimpleMongoRepository.java:154) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.0.jar!/:3.4.0]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.findAll(SimpleMongoRepository.java:61) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.0.jar!/:3.4.0]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:529) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:639) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar!/:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:163) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar!/:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar!/:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar!/:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar!/:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar!/:5.3.20]
        at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy84.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar!/:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar!/:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar!/:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.20.jar!/:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar!/:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar!/:5.3.20]
        at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy84.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at com.example.Person.view.PersonProcessor.process(PersonProcessor.java:23) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.example.Person.view.FileCSV.getFromCSV(FileCSV.java:24) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.example.Person.PersonApplication.onStart(PersonApplication.java:28) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:344) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar!/:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:229) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar!/:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:166) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar!/:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar!/:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar!/:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar!/:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:421) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar!/:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:378) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar!/:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.ready(EventPublishingRunListener.java:114) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$ready$6(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:82) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:120) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:114) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.ready(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:82) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:323) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
        at com.example.Person.PersonApplication.main(PersonApplication.java:22) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[springboot-docker-togepi.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[springboot-docker-togepi.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[springboot-docker-togepi.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[springboot-docker-togepi.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BaseCluster.getDescription(BaseCluster.java:180) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SingleServerCluster.getDescription(SingleServerCluster.java:44) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate.getConnectedClusterDescription(MongoClientDelegate.java:144) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.6.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate.createClientSession(MongoClientDelegate.java:101) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.6.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.getClientSession(MongoClientDelegate.java:291) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.6.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:183) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.6.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.execute(MongoIterableImpl.java:135) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.6.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.iterator(MongoIterableImpl.java:92) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.6.0.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:2968) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.0.jar!/:3.4.0]
```

In my application.yml:

```
    spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude=org:
      springframework:
        boot:
          autoconfigure:
            security: SecurityAutoConfiguration
  #colori per console
  output:
    ansi:
      enabled: ALWAYS
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: mongodb://User:Password@127.0.0.1:27017/DB_NAME?authSource=admin
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
server:
  error:
    include-message: always
jwt:
  secret: secret
file:
  input: name.csv
  assets: src\main\resources\person-fe\src\assets\


logging:
  level:
    org:
      springframework:
        data:
          mongodb:
            core:
              MongoTemplate: DEBUG
```

In my docker-compose:

```
    version: "3.8"  #versione di docker-compose
#creo services che dicono a docker come buildare e runnare
services:
  db:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    #direcory del database
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: User
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: Password
    volumes:
      - ./mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro
  #web ed api sono nome scelti a caso, l'importante e' il percorso
  web:
    build: ./PersonBE/src/main/resources/person-fe
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
  api:
    #usare queste due righe solo per prendere il docker file presente nel progetto (questa riga contiene il path)
    build: ./PersonBE
    #porta dove run il nostro DockerFile
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    #connessione mongodb://nome dell'host (quello alla riga di sotto dove prendiamo l'immagine)/nome del database
    # environment:
    #   DB_URL: mongodb://db/Person

volumes:
  Person:
```

My Dockerfile:

```
    FROM openjdk:17
ENV APP_HOME=/usr/app/
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
ADD target/Person-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar springboot-docker-people.jar
EXPOSE 8082
CMD ["java", "-jar", "springboot-docker-people.jar"]
```

Please, somebody can help me, because I'm stuck here and I don't know what to do.

thanks to all

Comment: `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` in Docker almost always refers to the current container, not a different container.  You need to use the database container's Compose service name `db` in your setup here (maybe set a `SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI` environment variable).

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze thanks for the comment, when yo say I have to set this variable in docker-compose file :(SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI), which value should i give?

Comment: Try to set the SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI to mongodb://host.docker.internal:27017 and set the same host to application.properties/yml